# Where can I see the list of orders in the Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play-console

I the Play Console app, you can see the list of orders, with a lot of details. I can't find this view anywhere on the web version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Google Play Console website and from the side menu click on `Order Management`

[image]

Comment: Ah, you need to be on the app list... Thanks.